# How to setup web api controller for ZipFile

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, zip

I am trying to create and return a zip file with selected documents. The console shows that the selected DocumentId's are being sent from the Angular controller to the api but I am getting a null error.

ApiController

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(string[] id)
    {
        List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            Document document = context.Documents.Find(id);

            if (document == null)
            {
                if (document == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
                }
            }

            using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
            {
                // Make zip file
                foreach (var d in documents)
                {
                    var dt = d.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
                    string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}.pdf", dt, d.PipeName, d.LocationAb);
                    zipFile.AddEntry(fileName, d.DocumentUrl);
                }

                return ZipContentResult(zipFile);
            }
        }
    }

    protected HttpResponseMessage ZipContentResult(ZipFile zipFile)
    {

        var pushStreamContent = new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
        {
            zipFile.Save(stream);
            stream.Close(); // After save we close the stream to signal that we are done writing.
        }, "application/zip");

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = pushStreamContent };
    }
```

UPDATE

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] string[] id)
    {
        var documents = new List<Document>();
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            foreach (string doc in id)
            {
                Document document = context.Documents.Find(new object[] { doc });
                if (document == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
                }

                documents.Add(document);
            }

            using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
            {
                // Make zip file
                foreach (var d in documents)
                {
                    var dt = d.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
                    string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}.pdf", dt, d.PipeName, d.LocationAb);
                    zipFile.AddEntry(fileName, d.DocumentUrl);
                }

                return ZipContentResult(zipFile);
            }
        }
    }
```

ERROR

> {"The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible for this operation. Near WHERE predicate, line 1, column 82."}

STACKTRACE

```
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindInStore(WrappedEntityKey key, String keyValuesParamName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Find(Object[] keyValues)
   at  TransparentEnergy.ControllersAPI.apiZipPipeLineController.Get(String[] id)  in e:\Development\TransparentEnergy\TransparentEnergy\ControllersAPI  \BatchZipApi\apiZipPipeLineController.cs:line 25
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at  System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor. <>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[]  methodParameters)
   at  System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Exec       ute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at  System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpCo       ntrollerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments,  CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

[image: Watch Screenshot]

New Screenshot of watch after changing string[] id to List id
[image: new screenshot]

Comment: Have you done a step by step debugging to see which element is actually null? Also, I see you checking if the document is null twice. Is that intended?

Comment: Not intended! Thanks. As far as debugging what can else can I do. I set a break point at the null check and nothing is showing up.

Comment: I would set the break point to right after the first using, and use the step over. You can use the immediate console to check if the values you are looking for are null or not.

Comment: i set the break point at the first using statement and its showing up as null. what is the immediate console? I posted a picture of the Angular Controller.

Comment: You should set the break points in Visual Studio and see how the null result is generated in Visual Studio / C# code.

Comment: the raw view is showing a count = 0

Comment: What does the zipFile shows? Do you see the btye array it is suppose to return?

Comment: i posted a screenshot. I removed the null check, I couldnt get past it with step over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you forgot to copy all the code into the question you never add anything to the documents list object.

At the start you create a new List object named documents:

```
List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();
```

You then search for items and place them in a new document object:

```
Document document = context.Documents.Find(id);
```

Then when attempting to make the zip file you are accessing the first created List object that has nothing put into it.

```
foreach (var d in documents)
```

I believe this is then causing your save of the zip file to throw an exception

```
zipFile.Save(stream);
```

> In the find line above
>
> ```
> Document document = context.Documents.Find(id);
> ```
>
> did you intend
>
> ```
> documents = context.Documents.Find(id);
> ```

**UPDATE 2**

I set up a database with your information, created a MVC web api that takes a POST of JSON to pass the data.  This populates the list with items pulled from a database by ID.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ZipFileAction")]
public HttpResponseMessage ZipFiles([FromBody]int[] id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {//Required IDs were not provided
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
    }

    List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        foreach (int NextDocument in id)
        {
            Document document = context.Documents.Find(NextDocument);

            if (document == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }

            documents.Add(document);
        }

        using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
        {
            // Make zip file
            foreach (var d in documents)
            {
                var dt = d.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
                string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}.pdf", dt, d.PipeName, d.LocationAb);
                zipFile.AddEntry(fileName, d.DocumentUrl);
            }

            return ZipContentResult(zipFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no this is what i have Document document = context.Documents.Find(id);

Comment: I changed it and i am getting this  Cannot implicitly convert type 'TransparentEnergy.Models.Document' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TransparentEnergy.Models.Document>'

Comment: I did not know what the Find call could return and thought it might give you a list of items.  You either have to add a loop to build a document list, find a way to return a List of documents, or remove the List and move the loop code up to loop on your input parameter.

Comment: how would i add a loop to build the list?

Comment: See the updated answer, too much to add as a comment

Comment: k, i posted what i have. I changed the string in the foreach loop to a int? isnt that what the loop is looking for? i got a error with string, cannot convert char to string.  with what i have now i am getting the same error as the previous one.

Comment: my applicationdbcontext only has this public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }

Comment: Clarified my updated code.  Assuming you are passing the primary keys of the database items find the item that matches and add to the list.

Comment: the id's are null, when i have string[] id the id's are not passed and it comes out as null? thanks for your help

Comment: i cleaned up the post and added what i have. the only way the id's show up is if i add [fromUri]

Comment: Try changing to new string instead of new object.

Comment: i changed string[] id to List<string> id  still got error message but the watch is showing something different. i posted pic

Comment: i used this and then i needed to change my angular controller to post using ngResource instead of $http and it worked ! thanks for all your time.

Answer (score 1):

> {"The argument types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.String' are incompatible ..."}

Sounds like your key column is an int type and you are searching it using a string. Try changing the type of the parameter from string to int. I renamed it `ids` as it seems to be a list of document identifiers.

An optimized version would get all needed documents in a single query :

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] int[] ids)
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var documents = context.Documents.Where(doc => ids.Contains(doc.Id)).ToList();
        if (documents.Count != ids.Length)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
        {
            // Make zip file
            foreach (var d in documents)
            {
                var dt = d.DocumentDate.ToString("y").Replace('/', '-').Replace(':', '-');
                string fileName = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}.pdf", dt, d.PipeName, d.LocationAb);
                zipFile.AddEntry(fileName, d.DocumentUrl);
            }

            return ZipContentResult(zipFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int[] does not return any ids, when i change it back to string[] I get a error message saying string[] does not contain a definition of contains